# Monitor availability Decathlon's products

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I developed this Python script to monitor the availability of Decathlon's products.

The problem is that i get the same output "Unavailable" for all the products that i monitor, also if they are in stock. This because the product in stock and the one not in stock have the same script. Which part of the Decathlon script do I have to scrape?

Here's my program:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
}

url = 'https://www.decathlon.it/kit-manubri-e-bilanciere-50-kg-id_8501164.html'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

soup.encode('utf-8')
def send_notifcation():
    print('Sending notification to discord...')

def product_checker():
    title = soup.find( id = 'productName').get_text()
    price = soup.find(id = 'real_price_value').get_text()
    available = soup.find(attrs={'class':"unavailability"}).get_text()
    print(title)
    print(price)
    print (available)
    if available=='Disponibile': #'Disponibile' means 'available in Italian.
        send_notifcation()

while(True):
  print("\nChecking product... \n")
  product_checker()
  time.sleep(2 * 30)

#"Prodotto non disponibile online." means "Product not available online."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `class` name is acting with different names: **availability** and **unavailability**.

where `availability` = Disponibile

and   `unavailability` = Prodotto non disponibile online.

Also it's presented within multiple span in the source script.

But to get an accurate result so we can query the `JSON` dict directly with regex to check `availability` using the following:

```py
import requests
import re

urls = ['kit-manubri-e-bilanciere-50-kg-id_8501164.html',
        'trampolino-esagonale-240-id_8605632.html']


def main(site):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(site.format(url))
            match = re.search('availability.+org\/(.*?)"', r.text)
            print("url: {:<70}, status: {}".format(r.url, match.group(1)))


main("https://www.decathlon.it/{}")
```

Output:

```
url: https://www.decathlon.it/kit-manubri-e-bilanciere-50-kg-id_8501164.html, status: InStoreOnly
url: https://www.decathlon.it/trampolino-esagonale-240-id_8605632.html     , status: InStock
```